# Passing object into class method dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object, overriding

I am trying to pass in an object so that it will be modified by the method defined `infection`. However, when I do pass it in, as I show below, it only does it once. This is my first experience making dynamic objects, so I'm not quite sure how to get it to keep going.

```py
class Region:
    def __init__(self, name, population, cases, deaths):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.cases = cases
        self.deaths = deaths
        print(name, cases)       

    def infection(self, name, population, cases):
        while population > cases:
            cases = cases + 1
            return (cases)        
    
westernEurope = Region("Western Europe", 1000000, 0, 0)
print(westernEurope.infection("Western Europe", 1000000, 0))
```

What I want to happen is that the infection method should keep incrementing until it reaches the number of cases, but I also need to be able to print each incrementation. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an indentation problem with your code.

This should work for your requirement:

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, name, population, cases, deaths):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.cases = cases
        self.deaths = deaths
        print(name, cases)       

    def infection(self, name, population, cases):
        while population > cases:
            cases = cases + 1
            print(cases)
        return (cases)        
    
westernEurope = Region("Western Europe", 1000000, 0, 0)
print(westernEurope.infection("Western Europe", 1000000, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks man! Sometimes it can be as little as an indentation.

Comment: But other functionalities can't be done while the infection loop is running, means until cases is not equal to population, no other math, no other printing can be done, at least without multiprocessing so, beware this is very requirement specific.

Comment: I will be implementing multiprocessing, so it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Awesome @AranKhalastchi, please consider accepting the answer if it resolves you query so that the question is marked completed.

Answer (score 0):

Infection() changes class attribute cases and prints it at each loop

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, name, population, cases, deaths):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.cases = cases
        self.deaths = deaths
    
    def infection(self):
        while self.population > self.cases:
            self.cases += 1
            print(self.name, self.cases)        
    
westernEurope = Region("Western Europe", 100, 0, 0)
westernEurope.infection()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was also unsure about how my code was presented, and this makes it look much cleaner and efficient. Thank you for this!

Answer (score -1):

It is because return immediately terminates the running of the function, so don't have the while loop in the function but in your main area, like this:

```
def infection(self, name, population, cases):
    cases = cases + 1

while population > cases:
    infection(pass all parameters)
```